# What does it mean when facebook is showing "index of /" text when sharing?

Tags: facebook, sharing

I shared my site in fb and in place where the image should be it says just "index of /". ??

I have these in my head:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Graphic design etc other stuff..." />
<meta property="og:title" content="Audiovisual" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:image" content="/images/ogimage.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://audiovisuaalinen.work/english.html" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://audiovisuaalinen.work/english.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1385587538423284" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Found what made this. It was .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control more of what Facebook uses in their snippets, you can add [open graph tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to your site. Then Facebook will use those tags to populate the title, description, thumbnail, etc. when shared on Facebook.

Comment: I have all open graphs on this site. They've been working fine in earier sites I've made but now this weird "index of"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an absolute URL for the Open Graph image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://audiovisuaalinen.work/images/ogimage.png" />
```